# column from table directly divided

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php script:

```
$prevNum = 0;

$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "Consommation";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "yyy";

$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); // fill in connection string

mysql_select_db("Consommation", $db);

$sql = 'update Consommation t1  
set diff=value-coalesce((select value from 
                (select id,value from Consommation) t2
                where t2.id<t1.id 
                order by t2.id desc limit 1),1)';

mysql_select_db('Consommation');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);


?>
```

which is populating the column diff from the table Consommation with the difference of two consecutive rows like:

```
id     date      time      value     diff
1  2013-01-27   9:37:41    49402      0
2  2013-01-27   9:40:08    49405      3
3  2013-01-27  10:22:01    49506     101
```

What I would like to do is have the column diff with the difference directly divided by 100 like:

```
id     date      time      value     diff
1  2013-01-27   9:37:41    49402      0
2  2013-01-27   9:40:08    49405     0.03
3  2013-01-27  10:22:01    49506     1.01
```

What should I change in the PHP script  (update ) ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can't you just add `/ 100` to the SQL?

Comment: please, stop using mysql_* functions, use mysqli or PDO, god, it's 2014...

Answer (score 1):

Just put a division by 100 into the expression:

```
$sql = 'update Consommation t1  
        set diff=(value-coalesce(
                    (select value 
                     from (select id,value from Consommation) t2
                     where t2.id<t1.id 
                     order by t2.id desc limit 1),1))/100';
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I explained what I changed, what more is there to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'update Consommation t1  
        set diff=(value-coalesce((select value from 
            (select id,value from Consommation) t2
            where t2.id<t1.id 
            order by t2.id desc limit 1),1))/100';
```

Comment: Some notation about what was changed would make for a more helpful answer. (On the plus side, you didn't copy the entire code block, which would have made finding the change you made even more work.

Comment: note the open paren before 'value' and then   )/100  just before the terminating quotation mark.